# Is there a Windows API to re-read CMOS RTC immediately?

Tags: windows, winapi, real-time-clock

In [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/580625f8-cd3e-4d9e-bb97-672083f460c7/disable-synchronizing-with-hardware-clock) discussion it is said that Windows re-reads CMOS RTC approximately every hour. Is there an API in Windows to re-read date/time from CMOS RTC immediately?

In other words: running a multi-OS machine, there is a need to instruct Windows: "CMOS contents has changed (by another OS running in parallel on the same machine). Please re-read time from it". Is there a standard API for that?

[Here](http://www.on-time.com/rtos-32-docs/rttarget-32/reference-manual/real-time-clock-and-cmos-ram/rtcmossetsystemtime.htm) is the function that does the job in RTOS-32.

In GNU/Linux, the equivalent action is: [hwclock --hctosys](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hwclock.8.html)

In QNX Neutrino, the command is: [rtc hw](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/am11/topic/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/r/rtc.html)

Comment: Do you wish to get the time itself directly, or do you wish Windows to update its own clock on demand? (I don't know if either is possible, but it's important to know the difference)

Comment: Preferably, in one atomic operation: CMOS time → Windows system time. But two separate calls would also suffice, of course.

Comment: You know that Windows usually syncs to a server that's much more accurate than the CMOS clock, right?

Comment: Right. But the problem has nothing to do with time synchronization (and my machine isn't connected to internet anyway).